# Ninject Nao criando a classe NinjectWebCommon

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

Estou instalando o *package do ninject*, porém não é criada a classe *NinjectWebCommon* automaticamente na pasta *App_Start*.

Alguém tem alguma solução? estou instalando a versão *Ninject.MVC5.*

Comment: Tenta: `Update-Package -reinstall -ProjectName NomeDoProjeto`

Comment: Nada...Nao aparece o arquivo...

Answer (score 1):

A ultima versão do Ninject.MVC5. Mudou e não criar mais o `NinjectWebCommon`  no `App_Start`, no lugar disso você tem que alterar o arquivo `Global.asax.cs` herdando o `NinjectHttpApplication`.

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        base.OnApplicationStarted();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();
    }
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var modules = new NinjectModule[] { new ModulosNinject() };
        return new StandardKernel(modules);
    }
}
```

Veja o exemplo [aqui](https://github.com/MarconcilioSouza/LojaVirtual/blob/master/LojaVirtual.UI.MVC/Global.asax.cs) e [aqui](https://github.com/MarconcilioSouza/LojaVirtual/blob/master/LojaVirtual.Infra.CrossCutting.IoC/Modulos/ModulosNinject.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Na versão 3.3.0 do Ninject eu tive esse problema:

Install-Package Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost -Version 3.3.1

Install-Package WebActivatorEx -Version 2.2.0

No meu caso a classe NinjectWebCommon.cs já apareceu  no App_Start.

Caso não apareça você pode criar uma classe NinjectWebCommon no App_Start  e continuar